# Do I need to worry about this discoloration on my wall?

Tags: drywall, moisture

This has been discoloring over years. Obviously it’s where the insulation ends and the drywall is exposed in the attic space. I know nothing about home stuff… how serious is this? Of note, it is not this obvious in real life. The Ring cam makes it look way worse.
Located in SF Bay Area, for weather reference. House built in 1970s. We added more blow in insulation about 6 years ago to help regulate the temp in the house.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Joist shadows/ghosting is common as dirt/dust.

Most cases is the opposite with the joists darkening.

Depending on your location (cold), adding insulation in that wall might be in your future. It is caused by inside warm moist air (containing dust) hitting a cooler section of the wall/ceiling and depositing the dust/dirt there.

Most homes, the joists/studs will transfer cold better than the bay/spaces between them, filled with insulation.

Your case seems that the bays are colder than the studs.  Maybe because of a lack of insulation between the bays/spaces.

The usual fix is to get someone up there on a ladder and start washing the wall/ceiling.  Have fun.